# Passing arguments URL in Code Igniter

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

I coded a view in my CodeIgniter project to create and edit events. There are two types of events. The method "create_event($type)" recieves a parameter to know the type of the event that the user wants to create. This parameter is readed by routes.php

If the user writes the URL "www.web.com/create_event", I load the basic event form.
If the user writes the URL "www.web.com/create_poll", I load the poll event form.

This is controlled by routes.php file.

When user do any mistakes on the creation form, I reload the creation form view displaying error messages and loading all the data that the user wrotes, but I don't know how to distinguish between the "basic event" form and "poll event" form.

I'm using load->view('create_event_view',$data) and I don't know how to do it.

Any solutions?

Thanks

Comment: How about a hidden input field on each form? Then, when submitted, check for the value of the hidden input.

Comment: expanding on what craig put, you would have an hidden field on the page. You would then assign a value to this through the loading controller, this would mean you could easily identify what form sent the request. Another method would be to have the form submit to a URL that can be set within the controller, so the event form would submit to the event controller and the poll form would submit to the poll controller. There are lots of other methods, too numerous to mention, but this should be a very easy task to sort out. Good Luck :)

Comment: I thought about a hidden input, but I'm finding for a better solution. Also, the hidden input solution is not valid because 'routes.php' doesn't read properly the $_POST values... :(

Comment: what about session? when loading, you write a var in your controller called $this->session->set_userdata('type_event', 'your_event'). When going back, you check for any data set, if the type_event is there, you're done

Comment: The $type variable is still missing with this solution. 
I need to write something like this "create_event/0" or "create_event/1" because is what my create_event function wants to read. If it is not written like this, it shows an error message saying that $type variable is missing at create_event() in event controller...